# What will be the answer?

Tags: calculation-puzzle

What is the answer of the given puzzle?
Please send solution.

```
------------------
| 190 | 60 | 200 |
------------------
|  40 | 210 | 90 |
------------------
|  5  |  ?  | 1  |
------------------
```

> What is the value of the question mark **?**

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! (Take the **[Tour]!**)  I'm glad you're eager to contribute a puzzle here, but I suspect this one may not fare well.  If you can't make enough effort to type your numbers in, instead of presenting  us with a badly cropped, *sideways* picture of a poorly scrawled number grid written with a lousy pen, you probably shouldn't expect much effort in return.  You really may want to look around at how other similar puzzles are presented here, and see if you can make yours easier and more appealing to would-be solvers.

Comment: @Rubio to be fair, though, most of the pens I come across are worse than this.

Comment: Discuss about the answer. Don't involve the pen here.

Comment: Is the R2C1(reading from rotated left, row 2 column 1) 40 or 90?

Comment: It is 40. Not 90.

Answer (score 6):

Is it

> **224**

Because

> First row  >  190 + 60  + 200 = 450

and

> Second row >  40  + 210 + 90  = 340

and

> Third row  >  5   + ?   + 1   = 230

So

> ? = 230 - 5 - 1 = 224

Answer (score 3):

Ignore the final column. We have $190+60=250$, $40+210=250$, so

> $$5+?=250\implies ?=245$$

Of course, there could be many other interpretations.